# Check database for css style user picked with php and mysql

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, css

I was wondering if there is any way that you can check with PHP when a user logs in what style they have for the site? 1, 2, or 3. I have the logic I just don't know how to have PHP grab that file and make it the main CSS file if the user likes 1 , and if they like 2 they can choose it and set that as the theme of the site.

Comment: What do you mean, `i have the logic`? You should show what you have so far.

Comment: like i know how to do it i just dont know the code to make it grab that file

Comment: `echo` the filename where you put your css file? Impossible to tell without more information.

Comment: okay in the database there will be a table and in that table there would be a field "style" and in there it would either say 1 , 2 , or 3 now how do i make php query the database on log in and switch the css file so it shows there corresponding style in the database that they have chosen ?

Comment: Hint: Conditional statements

Comment: Have you got a `Foreign key` in the style table, that references the user_id in the users table?

Comment: Alternatively instead of a database lookup everytime, you could save the value in a cookie, and then use a `switch` statement, to switch which `stylesheet` to output. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement

Answer (score 2):

Once the user selects the style, which should be done in a form,  get the input selected value, store it inside a **session** and use it over the whole user navigation.

```
$ids=filter_var($_POST[`id_style`], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$_SESSION[`style`]=$ids;
```

Then at each page, to call **css** file just

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/css_<?php echo $_SESSION[`style`]; ?>.css">
```

This method avoids permanent requests to the database,  otherwise if you want to track your users preferences,  before creating the **session**,  insert the user selected style in a table and after saving your user preference,  hold it in a session.  This way you achieve less response times and less server loads.